# What does it mean that $u$ and $v$ are solutions of this equation?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $u$ a Lipschitzian function vanishing at $0$ and $T$, $f\in L^1([0, T])$ a T-periodic function and consider the problem
$$(\phi(u^{\prime})^{\prime} - u =f(x).$$

During the math class, the professor said this: suppose that $u, v$ are two solutions of the problem. Thus
$$\int_0^T [\phi(u^{\prime}(x)-\phi(v^{\prime}(x)]^{\prime} [u(x)-v(x)] -[u(x)-v(x)]^2 dx=0.$$

I have two questions about that:

1. Probably he means that are solutions in the distributional sense. In this case, shouldn’t that be
   $$\int_0^T [\phi(u^{\prime}(x)-\phi(v^{\prime}(x)] [u(x)-v(x)]^{\prime} -[u(x)-v(x)]^2 dx=\int_0^T f(x) [u(x)- v(x)] dx?$$
2. Maybe the term
   $$\int_0^T f(x) [u(x)- v(x)] dx$$
   is missing? Or he is using the fact that $f$ is t-periodic?

Could someone please help me answering my questions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. Problably, the professor meant solution in the sense of strong solutions or classical solutions, so that the differential equation holds (almost?) everywhere.
2. First, subtract the differential equations satisfied by $u,v$, then test with $u-v$.

Comment: daw, as always, thank you for the answer. May I ask you to better clarify, please? About point 1., you mean $u$ is a classical solution if $\int_0^T (\phi(u^{\prime})^{\prime}u -u^2) dx =\int_0^T f(x) u dx$?

Comment: About point 2., you mean I need to do $\int_0^T (\phi(u^{\prime})^{\prime}u -u^2) dx =\int_0^T f(x) u dx$, then $\int_0^T (\phi(v^{\prime})^{\prime}v -v^2) dx =\int_0^T f(x) v dx$ and then test again with $u-v$? Actually, I do not even understand where the "intermediate" terms $-\phi(u^{\prime})^{\prime} v$ and $-\phi(v^{\prime})^{\prime} u$ come from (in the expression at first line).

Comment: classical solution == $u$ is smooth and the differential equation is satisfied with classical derivatives and for all t

Comment: For 2: test the equations for $u,v$ both with $u-v$ then subtract.

Comment: For point 2., now it is clear. For point 1., so it right to write that $u$ is a classical solution iff $\int_0^T (\phi(u^{\prime})^{\prime} -u)u dx =\int_0^T f(x) u dx$?